# Unable to do passwordless login to FreeNAS

Tags: ssh, unix, permissions, freebsd, freenas

I'm trying to use this command to allow me passwordless login to a FreeNAS box:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@server.com 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

But I get:

```
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys: Read-only file system.
```

If I log in to box as `root`, then `ls ~/.ssh` I see

```
drwx------  2 root  wheel   512 Aug 22 18:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   512 Sep  1 19:16 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   806 Aug 22 18:39 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  1675 Aug 18 21:50 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   400 Aug 22 18:34 known_hosts
```

And if I `ls ~` I see

```
drwx------   2 root  wheel   512 Aug 22 18:34 .ssh/
```

What am I missing? Why can't I add an entry to known_hosts?

Comment: I guess your device's filesystem is read-only, just like the error says. What type of filesystem is it? What's the underlying device (likely an `mtdblock` device)?

Comment: As a side-note, I'd recommend using [**ssh-copy-id**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-copy-id) to copy the key if possible.

Answer (score 7):

Login to your FreeNas Machine and open the Terminal enter:

```
mount -o rw /
```

when done enter

```
mount -o ro /
```

Answer (score 2):

In current version (9.2.1.8) this is very straight forward to achieve:

1. Log in to the Web GUI.
2. Navigate to **Account > Users > View Users**
3. Double click on user **root**.
4. In the open dialog box there is an "SSH Public Key" field. Copy and paste the content of

> /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

on the Admin node and Save the configuration.

If there is no **id_rsa.pub** copy the content of

> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable "root" login from the FreeNAS GUI if you want to use the "root" user over ssh. (which in the ssh best practice config, is DON'T DO IT). I use my user to ssh in to the FreeNAS and Then "su" up to the root user. Or you can allow your user sudo access.

http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/SSH & http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Users